# Optimizing a file navigator

Tags: php

I've come up with a basic file navigator that accepts user input to jump to different directories. The only problem I have with it is that I'm basically looping over the data three times:

1. Get a valid list of all directories for comparison against user input
2. Build a "sorted" list of directories and files
3. Output final list

Any tips on optimizing or improving this code?

```
define('ROOT', '/path/to/somewhere');

// get a list of valid paths
$valid = array();
$dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(ROOT);
$dir->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$iter = new ParentIterator($dir);
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iter, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $file) {
    $path = str_replace(ROOT, '', $file->getPathname());
    $valid[] = $path;
}

// user input
$subpath = isset($_GET['path']) && in_array($_GET['path'], $valid) ? $_GET['path'] : NULL;

$cwd = isset($subpath) ? ROOT.$subpath : ROOT;

// build and sort directory tree
$files = array();
foreach(new DirectoryIterator($cwd) as $file) {
    if($file->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }

    if($file->isDir()) {
        $path = str_replace(ROOT, '', $file->getPathname());
        $count = iterator_count(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($file->getRealPath(), FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS));
        $files[$path]['name'] = $file->getFilename();
        $files[$path]['count'] = $count;
    } else {
        $files[] = $file->getFilename();
    }
    asort($files);
}

// output directory tree
if(!empty($files)) {
    foreach($files as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            echo "<a href=\"?path=$key\">{$value['name']} ({$value['count']})</a><br />";
        } else {
            echo "$value<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `ParentIterator`? This will only show directories with sub-directories/files, and presumes you don't want to show empty directories to your users. This may well be the case, but what if they want to navigate into an empty directory and create a new file, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How often is the directory structure going to change? Can it be cached and the whitelist be re-generated only when there are changes instead of on each request? This would be my approach depending on requirements and load factors.Beyond that probably lies the realm of micro-optimizations.